# Can't make "composer require laravel/ui --dev" on laravel 6.5.1

Tags: php, laravel

I am getting following error :

> Can't make "composer require laravel/ui --dev" on laravel 6.5.1. I get an error 
>   "Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Problem 1:

- Conclusion: remove laravel/framework v6.5.1
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.5.1

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.

In my `composer.json`

```js
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": [
        "framework",
        "laravel"
    ],
    "license": "MIT",
    "require": {
        "php": "^7.2",
        "fideloper/proxy": "^4.0",
        "laravel/framework": "^6.2",
        "laravel/tinker": "^1.0",
        "laravelcollective/html": "^5.2.0",
        "tcg/voyager": "^1.3"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "facade/ignition": "^1.4",
        "fzaninotto/faker": "^1.4",
        "mockery/mockery": "^1.0",
        "nunomaduro/collision": "^3.0",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^8.0"
    },
    "config": {
        "optimize-autoloader": true,
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true
    },
    "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "dont-discover": []
        }
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        },
        "classmap": [
            "database/seeds",
            "database/factories"
        ]
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true,
    "scripts": {
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
            "@php artisan package:discover --ansi"
        ],
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "@php artisan key:generate --ansi"
        ]
    },
    "repositories": {
        "hooks": {
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "https://larapack.io"
        }
    }
}
```

Php version 7.2.25
Please, help.

Comment: Seems like your versions are incompatible with each other.

Comment: Check your PHP version, that must be stopping you from installing this package.

Answer (score 16):

Version 2 of laravel/ui isn't compatible with version 6 of Laravel so installs the version 1 with `composer require laravel/ui="1.*" --dev`

Answer (score 8):

**The command to implement Auth is as follows:**

```
composer require laravel/ui
php artisan ui vue --auth
```

**OR**

```
composer require laravel/ui --dev

php artisan ui vue --auth
```

**If your Login and Register page only shows plain HTML. And CSS is not loading properly then run this two command:**

```
npm install
npm run dev
```

Comment: "composer require laravel/ui" this command gives me the same error

Comment: check updated answer `composer require laravel/ui --dev`

Comment: I can't make "composer require laravel/ui" or "composer require laravel/ui --dev". I get the errors which I described in my question.

Comment: `"laravel/framework": "5.5.*",`
            change in your composer.json and after  run `composer update`

Comment: this is the best solution. after that I can make simple php artisan make:auth

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203981/discussion-between-vikas-katariya-and-nikolai92).

Comment: please mark as verified this answer if its help to you thank you @Nikolai92

Answer (score 4):

Try this command, it worked for me:

```
$ composer require laravel/ui "^1.2"
```

Answer (score 4):

composer require laravel/ui "^1.2" works...laravel 6 versions can only run 
laravel/ui 1.2.0:

See Packagist for older versions

https://packagist.org/packages/laravel/ui#v1.2.0. ----------------------

Also check out laravel 6 docs

https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/frontend -----------------------

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue with laravel 6.17. You can try to use this command instead :
 `composer require laravel/ui="1.*" - -dev` 
In my conclusion that laravel 6.x not compatible with laravel/ui version ^2.0. That command works for me.